# how to solve a eqaution of a parabola that passes through 3 points?

Tags: android

how do you find a equation of a parabola that passes through theses points: ( .0344,.9285), ( .4014, 1.4672), (1.002, -0.313).

how do you find a equation of a parabola that passes through theses points: ( .0344,-.75), ( .4014, -1.612), (1.002, -2.752).

Comment: You mean numerically, by writing a program? Do you know how to do this with pencil and paper? It seems like a question for the math site.

Answer (score 4):

How is this an Android question I'll never know...

Anyhow, this is simple high school math. So for you high-schoolers out there:

Say you have a standard quadratic equation:

`y = a*x^2 + b*x + c`

You have 3 unknown variables: `a`, `b` and `c`, and therefore you do need 3 points in order to solve those unknowns. Say you have 3 points: `(x1, y1)`, `(x2, y2)`, `(x3, y3)`.

This yields a system of 3 equations:

`y1 = a*x1^2 + b*x1 + c`

`y2 = a*x2^2 + b*x2 + c`

`y3 = a*x3^2 + b*x3 + c`

This corresponds to the following matrix equation:

```
|  x1^2   x1   1   | | a |     | y1 |
|  x2^2   x2   1   | | b |  =  | y2 |
|  x3^2   x3   1   | | c |     | y3 |
```

Simply solve this using Gaussian elimination method, or any other trivial matrix solving method. See Wikipedia entry here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination

Comment: plus one. I never saw this in high school though.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume a parabola of the form y=ax**2 + bx + c.  Plug in the x's and y's and you get three equations and three unknowns.  You can then use Gaussian elimination to calculate a b and c.

Answer (score 1):

Use wolfram alpha http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=equation+of+a+parabola+that+passes+through++%28+.0344%2C-.75%29%2C+%28+.4014%2C+-1.612%29%2C+%281.002%2C+-2.752%29